How to type Map so that keys and values have respective typings from a given interface
I have an interface containing event-typings akin to the following
interface Events {
  foo: (a: string,b: number) => void;
  bar: (a: boolean) => void;
}

Now, I want to create a Map instance where it's keys are constrained by the Events interface, so if a value of key of foo is used, it must adhere to Events.foo's typing.
Where I'm at
const listeners = new Map<keyof Events, { handler: ??, once: boolean}[]>();


You need to write your own Map typings, possibly as shown in the linked q/a above, demonstrated in this playground link. (Note that first you have to actually write out the type you're trying to store, such as {[K in keyof Events]: {handler: Events[K], once: boolean}[]}, possibly Partial if you want to allow for undefined)

(see prev comment) Every time this comes up, though, I wonder why the use case needs a Map instead of just a plain object, especially since the TS typings for Map don't do this job. It's so easy to just write const listeners: {[K in keyof Events]: {handler: Events[K], once: boolean}[]} = {foo:[], bar:[]} and use indexing instead of get/set.

You could try to make own Map with generic methods:
Playground
interface Events {
  foo: (a: string,b: number) => void;
  bar: (a: boolean) => void;
}

type Listener<F extends (...args: any) => any> = {handler: F, once: boolean};
class EventMap extends Map{
  set<K extends keyof Events>(key: K, listener: Listener<Events[K]>){
    this.set(key, listener);
    return this;
  }
  get<K extends keyof Events>(key: K): Listener<Events[K]> | undefined {
    return this.get(key);
  }
}

const listeners = new EventMap;

listeners.set('foo', {handler: (a, b) => {
  a; // string
  b; // number;
}, once: false});

const {handler} = listeners.get('foo')!; // const handler: (a: string, b: number) => void

